# extracting a substring in Delphi using SubStr + Copy?

Tags: delphi

I have a function in Delphi

```
var

  Ramoativ : String;
  filteredRamoativ: String;

begin

  Ramoativ := '15 - Serviços';

  filteredRamoativ := copy(Ramoativ, 1, SubString(Ramoativ, 1, '-'));

end;
```

The output must be = 15

The String can have more than 2 digits number, so Ramoativ can be '13823849 - Serviços', but the - will always separate the number from text.

My idea is using a function to locate the position of "-" and use it as an argument for copy, but I am having difficulties doing it

Comment: One option: Use `Pos`, `Trim`, and `Copy`.

Comment: `Copy(Ramoative, 1, Pos('-', Ramoativ) - 1)` will work.

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/resources/white-papers -> Object Pascal Handbook

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is the correct way to go.  However, Delphi does not have a `SubString()` function.  To search for the position of a substring in another string, use the [`System.Pos()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) function instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  Ramoativ : String;
  P: Integer;
  filteredRamoativ: String;
begin
  Ramoativ := ...;
  P := Pos('-', Ramoativ);
  if P <> 0 then
    filteredRamoativ := Trim(Copy(Ramoativ, 1, P-1))
  else
    filteredRamoativ = '';
end;
```

Also, Delphi has a [`StrUtils.LeftStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.LeftStr) function to extract a substring from the left-hand edge of a string, eg:

```pascal
var
  Ramoativ : String;
  P: Integer;
  filteredRamoativ: String;
begin
  Ramoativ := ...;
  P := Pos('-', Ramoativ);
  if P <> 0 then
    filteredRamoativ := Trim(LeftStr(Ramoativ, P-1))
  else
    filteredRamoativ = '';
end;
```